# Multiple filters on exists

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm trying to filter my *exists* query set into looking through 3 fields to check if a release date of this game, platform and region already exists.

What I seek to accomplish:

```
if ReleaseDate.objects.filter(game=game.id).filter(platform=release_date_object['platform']).filter(region=release_date_object['region']).exists():
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple - just put them all together in one filter() with commas:

```
if ReleaseDate.objects.filter(game=game.id, platform=release_date_object['platform'], region=release_date_object['region']).exists():
```

Sometimes more complicated queries require Q objects but for a simple multiple-field query just put them all in one filter().

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following using [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/):

```
if ReleaseDate.objects.filter(Q(game=game.id) & Q(platform=release_date_object['platform']) & Q(region=release_date_object['region'])).exists()
```

This makes sure each of the arguments in the filter are true.